# OpenCart - как добавить перевод строки?

Tags: php, opencart

Создал дополнительное условие при заказе товара, но никак не получается добавить перевод для этой строки.

```
    <div class="form-group required">
    <input id="agree" type="checkbox" placeholder="Условия" class="control-label" for="input-payment-rules" required> <?php echo $column_rules; ?>
</div>
```

Прописал в /catalog/language/en-gb/checkout/checkout.php

```
$_['column_rules']                    = 'I agree with rules and terms of delivery';
```

вместо текста - пустота. Подскадите, пожалуйста, как зарегистрировать эту переменную?

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в контроллер:

```
$data['column_rules'] = $this->language->get('column_rules');
```

Контроллер расположен по этому пути: admin\controller\